# Manage keypress

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, masm, masm32

I'm using MASM syntax , and I want to get a keyboard key press then store it to use it later in code , I've tried using : int 21h interrupt but it seems that it doesn't work under 32-bit.

Is there any other way to achieve that ?

thanks.

Comment: What environment is your program running in?

Comment: Windows7 ,32-bit. I forgot to mention that the program is based on a console actually.

Comment: You'll have to run your program in an emulator like DosBox. Or make it a Windows console application instead (which means using the Win32 API instead of interrupts).

Comment: Which Win32 API you think is best to achieve such goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to switch to Windows, you could probably use the [`GetKeyboardState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to find out if one or more keys are being pressed. Even easier than using `GetKeyboardState` would be to use something like the following:

```
.486
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap : none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data?
key dd ?

.code

start:

printf("Press a key..")
call crt__getch
mov key,eax
printf("\nYou pressed key number %d", key)

invoke ExitProcess,0

END start
```